# Switching between different table views

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a rather complex subclass UITableViewController.  On top of this, data in the tableview  can be sorted in one of three ways, based on a user setting (accessed on a different view).  Each of the settings requires different sorting and grouping of the tableview, although the behavior of the items in the rows is common (for example the select action for each row is the same, regardless of the display settings.  Similarly, the top and bottom toolbars are consistent). This leads to a lot of branching on my code based on the user setting applied.

Is there a nice way to divide this out a little?  I considered three separate subclasses of UITableView, but then I lose the commonality.  So maybe an abstract custom UITableView subclass, with three subclasses inheriting from there?  How would I switch between the instances when the setting is changed?

Perhaps you have a better idea?  Since only the contents of the tableview itself change, I would like to avoid repeating and maintaining the same code three times.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single UITableViewController.  Lets call the UITableViewController RootViewController.

When the RootViewController is loaded you could load a indictor of which type of sort will take place.  I would probably just store the setting in the NSUserDefaults, and load the user's setting choice in the viewDidLoad method of the RootViewController.

Just use that settings choice as a kind of flag like the example below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if ([sortType isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
        // return number of rows
    }
    else if ([sortType isEqualToString:@"Distance"]) {
        // return number of rows
    }
    else {
        // return number of rows
    }
}
```

You would just need to do this in each method of the table that would be affected, by the sort type.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I currently have - three if clauses for each method, and so a lot of hard to read code.  I was wondering if there is a way to move these into subclasses or divide the functionality some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a params for the tableview datasource, like "hot", "new", "near", and when user switch the tableview, you can just change the value of params, and then reload your tableview.